# Price values have converted from 4 digit number to 1 digit

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send item revenue to GA4 through GTM event parameters. Some of the product revenues seem correct, random products seem to be converted to a 1-digit-2-decimal format. Example below: (but with item price cause I couldn't reproduce the same issue)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMvBR.png)

I tried with the same product but the results differed, the second attempt example below with console view: (still item price)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx1xe.png)

Even in the same product price value differs on occasion. My question is why this can be happening and how can I prevent this issue further?

Comment: Just wonder where the datalayer comes from and should look into there to see what cause the issue.